# Making a gif from a video

Tags: video, mac

I have a video clip that I want to convert to gif. I used this app: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gifbrewery/id435989461

But I couldn't figure out how to make a gif that's the proper speed. The default preview they showed had way too many frames missing, so i increased the frame count. But once I did that the gif played way too slowly. How do I make the gif speed simply the same speed as the original video?

I also used MPEG Streamclip to export to PNGs so I can use GIMP to create the GIF. Same problem, couldn't create a proper speed GIF.

Answer (score 2):

The GIMP has a GIF Animation Package that can convert MP4 to gif.

You can just use the Split Video into Frames function, which will split each frame into a layer in GIMP.

Then when you Save As, select .gif and choose Save as Animation.

Photoshop has a similar function, but I haven't used it for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [GifNinja](http://gifninja.com/).

It is web based.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format you might be able to use [MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) or [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), both of which are installable via [MacPorts](http://macports.org/).